# How to merge sub-arrays in multidimensional array if names are similar

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I'm trying to merge two arrays. One array has names, and other has values. I want to merge them in a single multidimensional array in a way that values are in same sub-array if their names are similar. I'm new to programming and haven't been able to do anything

Names:

```
Array
(
    [0] => TestAgent
    [1] => TestAgent1
    [2] => TestAgent1
    [3] => TestAgent2
    [4] => TestAgent2
    [5] => TestAgent2
)
```

Values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019-04
    [1] => 2019-05
    [2] => 2019-06
    [3] => 2019-04
    [4] => 2019-05
    [5] => 2019-06
)
```

This is desired output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => TestAgent
        [1] => 2019-04
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => TestAgent1
        [1] => 2019-05
        [2] => 2019-06
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => TestAgent2
        [1] => 2019-04
        [2] => 2019-05
        [3] => 2019-06
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you explain that why your desired arrays first element has ```TestAgent``` and ```2019-04``` only and the last element has ```TestAgent2``` and 3 date.

Comment: @Cotur this is a demo data to be replaced by actual data later

Comment: @andreas What do i do if i wanted to get something like this

Array
(
    [name] => TestAgent2
    [cats] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-04
            [1] => 2019-05
            [2] => 2019-06
        ),

)

Comment: @rakibulmuhajir you mean like this? https://3v4l.org/eB8L8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_intersect_key to get the matching values from the names array.

This method does not need sorted array(s).

```
$names = ['TestAgent1', 'TestAgent', 'TestAgent1', 'TestAgent1', 'TestAgent2', 'TestAgent2', 'TestAgent2'];
$values = ['2019-01', '2019-04', '2019-05', '2019-06', '2019-04', '2019-05', '2019-06'];

$unique = array_unique($names);

foreach($unique as $name){
    $res[] = array_merge([$name], array_intersect_key($values, array_intersect($names, [$name])));
}
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => TestAgent1
            [1] => 2019-01
            [2] => 2019-05
            [3] => 2019-06
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => TestAgent
            [1] => 2019-04
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => TestAgent2
            [1] => 2019-04
            [2] => 2019-05
            [3] => 2019-06
        )

)
```

https://3v4l.org/MWjv0

Answer (score 2):

Get the different counts of values from `array_count_values()` on the `$names` array, then use that to define the number of elements to use in `array_slice()`. The number of sliced elements adds to the count of the next offset.

```php
$counts = array_count_values($names);
$offset = 0;

foreach (array_values(array_unique($names)) as $key=>$name) {
    $slice = array_slice($values, $offset, $counts[$name]);
    $offset += count($slice);
    $result[$name] = $slice;
}

print_r($result);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/VtktR

Comment: @qirel i want to keep **name** at index 0 of each array

Comment: @rakibulmuhajir me personally would do as qirel did. It's easier in my opinion to have them as keys, but it's up to you. Either way works...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$one =
[
    'Testagent',
    'Testagent1',
    'Testagent1',
    'Testagent2',
    'Testagent2',
    'Testagent2'
];

$two =
[
    '2019-04',
    '2019-05',
    '2019-06',
    '2019-04',
    '2019-05',
    '2019-06'
];

$n = -1;
$previous = null;
foreach($one as $k=>$v) {
    if($v !== $previous)
        $items[++$n][] = $v;
    $items[$n][] = $two[$k];
    $previous = $v;
}

var_export($items);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'Testagent',
      1 => '2019-04',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 'Testagent1',
      1 => '2019-05',
      2 => '2019-06',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => 'Testagent2',
      1 => '2019-04',
      2 => '2019-05',
      3 => '2019-06',
    ),
  )
```

If the first array does not have grouped like values do an asort on them first.